# How to Remove these Ngon's with good topology?

Tags: topology

I'm working with a relatively low poly model for a weight bench, and am currently connecting the "legs" that support the weights.  I'm having an issue trying to determine how to clean up the highlighted parts below.  Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://topologyguides.com/page/2

Comment: Thank you!  the linked document helped me find solution :)

Comment: @MattC. If you found the answer, it would be great if you answer your question yourself. That way others can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the best way to do your shape is this one, and to do it you can just correct your topology with some merges and edge slides:

[image]